# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't set Envince as default pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, evince

I modified `~/.config/mimeapps.list`:

and set:

```
application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop;
```

Then logged out and back in.
but if I use `xdg-open /some/document.pdf` it says

```
Setting _INKSCAPE_GC=disable as a workaround for broken libgc
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/michael/online2021.pdf
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

And then open with Inkscape.

I get the impression the association has been set elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Set the association via the file manager. Find a PDF file, right-click, properties, and on the "Open with" tab, set "Document Viewer" as the default application.